# Unbind an element and add back after animation stops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to `unbind` an element, an then `bind` it back after a page scroll animation completes:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(".class1 a, .class2 a").unbind();
  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $('#container').offset().top}, 1000);
  $(".class1 a, .class2 a").bind();
});
```

`.class1 a` and `.class2 a` never get binded back, however?

Comment: `bind()` what? It does not know magically what you want to add, you need to tell it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind back the event handler after the animation you'll have to use a callback function. Also you have to pass a event type and callback to rebind the handler

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(".class1 a, .class2 a").unbind();
  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $('#container').offset().top}, 1000, function(){
      $(".class1 a, .class2 a").bind('sometype', somefunction);          
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `sometype` and `somefunction`?

Answer (score 0):

When you `bind` an event after unbinding  , it has no information of the `previous handler.`

So you need to assign the handler `every time you bind the event`.

```
$(".class1 a, .class2 a").bind(handler);
```

---

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(".class1 a, .class2 a").unbind();
  $('html, body').stop()
                 .animate({scrollTop: $('#container')
                 .offset().top}, 1000);
  $(".class1 a, .class2 a").bind(handler);
});

function handler(e){
   alert('Hey !!');
}
```

Also use `.on() /.off()`  instead of `.bind()/.unbind()` as the former have been superseeded by the later..

```
 $(".trigger").on('click', function(){
      $(".class1 a, .class2 a").off('click');
      $('html, body').stop()
                     .animate({scrollTop: $('#container')
                     .offset().top}, 1000);
      $(".class1 a, .class2 a").on('click' , handler);
    });

    function handler(e){
       alert('Hey !!');
    }
```